# Distinguishing POST from GET with window.location?

Tags: javascript

In our login/logout javascript, which works in a modal box, I'd like to reload the current page after a user logs in our out, but only if the current page was not loaded as a POST--I don't want to try to double post data to the server.

Is there any way to tell whether window.location.reload() will be sent as a GET or a POST, so that I can redirect POSTs to our front page instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have access to the request method [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121218/client-side-detection-of-http-request-method), but you could check with PHP if there is any POST data, and set a JS variable:

```
<script type="javascript">
    var post = <?php if(isset($_POST)) echo 'true'; else echo 'false'; ?>;
</script>
```

Although this is not reliable (users could manually change it) so you shouldn't rely on this to avoid duplicate data...

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll use window.location =window.location.href to avoid reposting, and maybe filter out some of the more obvious post links.