# How can a php POST be detected using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, post, webforms

### My situation

I have a piece of javascript that does several manipulations on a webform on form.php. The form is set to `action="form.php"` and thus loads itself upon submission. The webform is only built `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))`, so after posting, the input elements and containers that make up the webform are not there. This is generally how the code is structured:

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
//the form has not been submitted
?>
  <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="form" name="form">
    <!-- general input elements -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
<?php }
else {
// the form has been submitted
  // posted values are submitted to a database
}
?>
```

The javascript still tries to do manipulations on these elements, though. Since these aren't there anymore, errors occur. I could use a bunch of `if (HTMLElement)` statements for every manipulation to a certain HTMLElement, but I hope there is a more solid, more general solution.

### The question

Given that the form submits to its page and that it's not an option to simply keep showing the form after POSTing, do you have a suggestion how I can detect the POSTing of the webform and shut certain parts of my javascript down?

A more general question would be:

**How can a php POST be detected by javascript?**

Comment: Have you really SUBMITTED the form? or just reloaded the form through javascript? code please!

Comment: Could you not perform some PHP on the submission page, save the results to a session (or database etc), then reload the form page back to its original state?
If not why don't you use the same PHP IF condition on the javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Client-side detection of HTTP request method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121218/client-side-detection-of-http-request-method), Q: "Is it possible to detect the HTTP request method (e.g. GET or POST) of a page from JavaScript? If so, how?". A: **"In a word - No"**

Comment: Thank you for your input. Your comments have contributed to my understanding of the problem in a valuable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that comes to mind is something like this:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') $isPost = true; ?>

// later on in your script

<?php if (!$isPost): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
// the JS code that manipulates your form
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Basically, if the form was posted, don't render the JS code that manipulates it.  If that code is mixed with other code you always want included, then you'll have to work it a little differently.  In that case you could try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isPost = <?php echo $isPost ? 'true' : 'false' ?>;

if (!isPost) {
    document.getElementById('blah').doSomething();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I find your first suggestion a very good and elegant solution. All the javascript that manipulates the forms is essentially in one .js document, so I can simply call the file into action only `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))`. Thank you for your answer. This was exactly what I was looking for.