# Can Google Analytics distinguish multiples requests using methods such POST, PUT, DELETE on a single URL?

Tags: google-analytics, http-verbs

I'm working on a web application that uses node.js + express. Our team has decided that all related pages must use a single URL and be distinguished only by its method.

So, for example: we have a group edition page. `GET /groups` gets the html, which includes the edition form, and `POST /groups` saves the changes.

The issue is that I only desire to track the `POST /groups` request. However, on the Google Analytics configurations, I only found URL-related tracking, nothing about specific HTTP methods.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have implemented GA via the standard client-side tracking code then no, GA will not be aware of the http method ([JavaScript has no access to http headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121218/client-side-detection-of-http-request-method)). It should however be trivial to render a Javascript if condition into the code depending on the request method.